# почему build не работает так Как в редакторе в playMode?

Tags: c#, unity3d

В билде игра работает с ошибками [image: Build]Но в редакторе всё нормально [image: пути появляются в центре относительно позиции игрока]
Делал Devbuild в логах указывают на NullReferenceException Пробовал менять GameObjects в редакторе (удалил создал заново) не помогает
Так же в логах куча блоков с заголовком типа Reference to object "bbbb" is missing!
Reference to object "baaab" is missing!
Reference to object "ccccc" is missing!
В чём проблема ? Может ли это быть связаео с тем что редактор на Маке apple?

```
tarting managed debugger on port 56197
Using monoOptions --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,embedding=1,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:56197
Initialize engine version: 2021.3.11f1 (0a5ca18544bf)
[Subsystems] Discovering subsystems at path /Users/sergeypo/Desktop/no greed movemingFlash/notDeepDevBuild.app/Contents/Resources/Data/UnitySubsystems
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1; jobified=0
Hanns.G HQ191 preferred device: Intel HD Graphics 5000 (low power)
Metal devices available: 1
0: Intel HD Graphics 5000 (low power)
Using device Intel HD Graphics 5000 (low power)
Initializing Metal device caps: Intel HD Graphics 5000
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
- Completed reload, in  0.185 seconds
The referenced script (fieldofView) on this Behaviour is missing!
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 SerializableManagedRef::RebuildMonoInstance(Object*, ScriptingClassPtr, ScriptingObjectPtr, MonoScript*)
 #3 PersistentManager::ProduceObject(SerializedFile&, SerializedObjectIdentifier, int, ObjectCreationMode, PersistentManager::LockFlags)
 #4 PersistentManager::CreateThreadActivationQueueEntry(SerializedFile&, SerializedObjectIdentifier, int, bool, PersistentManager::LockFlags)
 #5 PersistentManager::PreallocateObjectThreaded(int, PersistentManager::LockFlags)
 #6 void ImmediatePtr<Unity::Component>::Transfer<StreamedBinaryRead>(StreamedBinaryRead&)
 #7 void StreamedBinaryRead::TransferSTLStyleArray<dynamic_array<GameObject::ComponentPair, 0ul> >(dynamic_array<GameObject::ComponentPair, 0ul>&, TransferMetaFlags)
 #8 void GameObject::TransferComponents<StreamedBinaryRead>(StreamedBinaryRead&)
 #9 void GameObject::Transfer<StreamedBinaryRead>(StreamedBinaryRead&)
 #10 GameObject::VirtualRedirectTransfer(StreamedBinaryRead&)
 #11 SerializedFile::ReadObject(long long, ObjectCreationMode, bool, TypeTree const**, bool*, Object&)
 #12 PersistentManager::ReadAndActivateObjectThreaded(int, SerializedObjectIdentifier const&, SerializedFile*, bool, bool, PersistentManager::LockFlags)
 #13 PersistentManager::LoadFileCompletelyThreaded(core::basic_string_ref<char>, long long*, int*, int, PersistentManager::LoadFlags, LoadProgress&, PersistentManager::LockFlags)
 #14 LoadSceneOperation::Perform()
 #15 PreloadManager::ProcessSingleOperation()
 #16 PreloadManager::Run()
 #17 PreloadManager::Run(void*)
 #18 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*)
 #19 _pthread_start
 #20 thread_start

The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'VisDirLeft') is missing!
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 ManagedMonoBehaviourRef::DoScriptRebuildWarning(Object*)
 #3 SerializableManagedRefTransfer::Transfer(Object*, SerializableManagedRef&, StreamedBinaryRead&, bool)
 #4 MonoBehaviour::VirtualRedirectTransfer(StreamedBinaryRead&)
 #5 SerializedFile::ReadObject(long long, ObjectCreationMode, bool, TypeTree const**, bool*, Object&)
 #6 PersistentManager::ReadAndActivateObjectThreaded(int, SerializedObjectIdentifier const&, SerializedFile*, bool, bool, PersistentManager::LockFlags)
 #7 PersistentManager::LoadFileCompletelyThreaded(core::basic_string_ref<char>, long long*, int*, int, PersistentManager::LoadFlags, LoadProgress&, PersistentManager::LockFlags)
 #8 LoadSceneOperation::Perform()
 #9 PreloadManager::ProcessSingleOperation()
 #10 PreloadManager::Run()
 #11 PreloadManager::Run(void*)
 #12 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*)
 #13 _pthread_start
 #14 thread_start

The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'player') is missing!
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 ManagedMonoBehaviourRef::DoScriptRebuildWarning(Object*)
 #3 SerializableManagedRefTransfer::Transfer(Object*, SerializableManagedRef&, StreamedBinaryRead&, bool)
 #4 MonoBehaviour::VirtualRedirectTransfer(StreamedBinaryRead&)
 #5 SerializedFile::ReadObject(long long, ObjectCreationMode, bool, TypeTree const**, bool*, Object&)
 #6 PersistentManager::ReadAndActivateObjectThreaded(int, SerializedObjectIdentifier const&, SerializedFile*, bool, bool, PersistentManager::LockFlags)
 #7 PersistentManager::LoadFileCompletelyThreaded(core::basic_string_ref<char>, long long*, int*, int, PersistentManager::LoadFlags, LoadProgress&, PersistentManager::LockFlags)
 #8 LoadSceneOperation::Perform()
 #9 PreloadManager::ProcessSingleOperation()
 #10 PreloadManager::Run()
 #11 PreloadManager::Run(void*)
 #12 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*)
 #13 _pthread_start
 #14 thread_start

The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'player') is missing!
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 ManagedMonoBehaviourRef::DoScriptRebuildWarning(Object*)
 #3 SerializableManagedRefTransfer::Transfer(Object*, SerializableManagedRef&, StreamedBinaryRead&, bool)
 #4 MonoBehaviour::VirtualRedirectTransfer(StreamedBinaryRead&)
 #5 SerializedFile::ReadObject(long long, ObjectCreationMode, bool, TypeTree const**, bool*, Object&)
 #6 PersistentManager::ReadAndActivateObjectThreaded(int, SerializedObjectIdentifier const&, SerializedFile*, bool, bool, PersistentManager::LockFlags)
 #7 PersistentManager::LoadFileCompletelyThreaded(core::basic_string_ref<char>, long long*, int*, int, PersistentManager::LoadFlags, LoadProgress&, PersistentManager::LockFlags)
 #8 LoadSceneOperation::Perform()
 #9 PreloadManager::ProcessSingleOperation()
 #10 PreloadManager::Run()
 #11 PreloadManager::Run(void*)
 #12 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*)
 #13 _pthread_start
 #14 thread_start

The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'view') is missing!
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 ManagedMonoBehaviourRef::DoScriptRebuildWarning(Object*)
 #3 SerializableManagedRefTransfer::Transfer(Object*, SerializableManagedRef&, StreamedBinaryRead&, bool)
 #4 MonoBehaviour::VirtualRedirectTransfer(StreamedBinaryRead&)
 #5 SerializedFile::ReadObject(long long, ObjectCreationMode, bool, TypeTree const**, bool*, Object&)
 #6 PersistentManager::ReadAndActivateObjectThreaded(int, SerializedObjectIdentifier const&, SerializedFile*, bool, bool, PersistentManager::LockFlags)
 #7 PersistentManager::LoadFileCompletelyThreaded(core::basic_string_ref<char>, long long*, int*, int, PersistentManager::LoadFlags, LoadProgress&, PersistentManager::LockFlags)
 #8 LoadSceneOperation::Perform()
 #9 PreloadManager::ProcessSingleOperation()
 #10 PreloadManager::Run()
 #11 PreloadManager::Run(void*)
 #12 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*)
 #13 _pthread_start
 #14 thread_start

UnloadTime: 1.976634 ms
rightAnimation
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)

rightAnimation
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)

rightAnimation
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)

4/5
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)

rightAnimation
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)

pred else
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)

3/5
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)

pred else
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)

2/5
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)

pred else
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)

1/5
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)

pred else
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)

0/5
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at restartYouLoose.TextPopUpWhenHealthoM () [0x00001] in /Users/sergeypo/Desktop/no greed movemingFlash/Assets/SCRIPTS/restartYouLoose.cs:62 
  at restartYouLoose.restartPosM (System.Boolean restartPosP) [0x000f3] in /Users/sergeypo/Desktop/no greed movemingFlash/Assets/SCRIPTS/restartYouLoose.cs:54 
  at MovementWithoutgrid.Update () [0x00022] in /Users/sergeypo/Desktop/no greed movemingFlash/Assets/SCRIPTS/MovementWithoutgrid.cs:371 

(Filename: /Users/sergeypo/Desktop/no greed movemingFlash/Assets/SCRIPTS/restartYouLoose.cs Line: 62)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: На кофейной гуще не гадаем. Mac тут не причем.

Comment: да и на логах вы тоже не очень...)